# Система частиц не проигрывается | Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
 using UnityEngine;

public class ShotBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float speedAmount = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject explosionPrefab;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speedAmount;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            

         //   Vector3 vector3 = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

            var explosion = Instantiate(explosionPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(explosionPrefab, 1f);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
      }
    }
```

Подскажите чё не так? при соприкосновении пули и врагов должна проигрываться система частиц, а она вообще не в какую, в функция заходит, но не проигрывается

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем сам разобрался у системы не было галки  Play On Awake
Перебздел и добавил ещё в коде :

```
 private void OnAwake()
    {
        explosionPrefab.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();

    }
```